# Angular momentum of an $N$-body system is of the form $Q(y,z)=y^TDz$?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

I was reading [in a book](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-30666-8) that the angular momentum of the $N$-body system is of the form $Q(y,z)=y^TDz$ with $y, z$ vectors and $D$ a matrix. But the angular momentum of the $N$-body system is something like $L=\sum_{i=1}^Nq_i\times p_i$ no? How do you put it in the previous form?

**edit :**

I am not sure if this helps but it is the citation that is causing me trouble.

> We next consider partitioned Runge-Kutta methods for systems
> $\dot{y}=f(y,z), \dot{z}=g(y,z)$. Usually such methods cannot conserve
> general quadratic invariants. We therefore concentrate on quadratic
> invariants of the form  \begin{equation} Q(y,z)=y^TDz \end{equation}
> where $D$ is a matrix of appropriate dimensions. Observe that the
> angular momentum of $N$-body systems is of this form.

Comment: You're going to have to specify a lot more information here because not everyone has access to the book you linked. You should just paraphrase the part that talks about this quantity.

Comment: Given that angular momentum is a vector quantity, and a quadratic form like what you wrote is going to give you a scalar, there must be something more to explain about what is going on here.